# Is there a view container where I can wire a ViewModel event to a View action?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, mvp

I have a collection of views and I would like to be able to call a method on the view in response to an event raised in the ViewModel.

I am currently using a ItemsControl with a DataTemplate but this does not give me an opportunity to intercept the View and ViewModel and wire them up.  Is there a container that is better suited for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

User :  Source Object is your ViewModel.

```
   <UserControl>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding}" EventName="YourEvent">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="YourMethod"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </UserControl>
```

If you place it in a scope of another element then your view (UserControl) 
add

```
 <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="YourMethod" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=yourUserControl}"/>
```